# AWS Lambda Python Code - Slack notification on ec2 shutdown - error - Task timed out

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My code below is for doing slack notification
I tested on normal python3.9 terminal works ok
In AWS UI of Lambda :-
General configuration - i change duration 15 min no luck
Increase RAM for fuction no luck
EventBridge (CloudWatch Events):   - i set & see the log error , so that config is not issue
VPC set to be same
EC2 full admin, Admin permission along with AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole-xxxx is set no luck

Log shows

```
2022-04-10T12:43:41.739-07:00   {'version': '0', 'id': 'f0b301f6-c7f6-634c-a13d-e48df95b7754', 'detail-type': 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification', 'source': 'aws.ec2', 'account': 'xxx', 'time': '2022-04-10T19:38:41Z', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'resources': ['arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxx:instance/i-xxxx'], 'detail': {'instance-id': 'i-0dccxxxx', 'state': 'pending'}}



2022-04-10T12:47:44.841-07:00   REPORT RequestId: 5097072f-db2a-46ae-85c0-39984277bead Duration: 243102.20 ms Billed Duration: 243000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 16 MB
2022-04-10T12:47:44.841-07:00   2022-04-10T19:47:44.841Z 5097072f-db2a-46ae-85c0-39984277bead Task timed out after 243.10 seconds
```

This was the code which was pack with virtual env & request etc was uploaded to s3 & shows up ok

Most possible reasons are, permission or VPC, i think is not case here ..

Below is also correct :
handler :
slackAlert.send_slack

Any suggestions please

```
import boto3
import json
import requests

webhook_url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/T03AWS5EYLU/xxxx/xxxx"


def send_slack(event, context):
  print(str(evebt))
  slack_message = {'text': 'EC2 Stopped'}
  response = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(slack_message))
  return response.text
```

Comment: Is your lambda in a private subnet in your vpc? Do you have NAT gateway in a public subnet?

Comment: Thanks for asking , Lambda is given access to subnet ( both )  to which IG is attached so that also can be ruled out ..

Comment: That's incorrect then. Lambda must be in private subnets. Those subnets don't have IG.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, in my case i removed the VPCs from Lambda & i got the messages in slack  ! @Marcin Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Lambda in a VPC does not have internet access, unless it is placed in a **private subnets** which have routes to a **NAT gateway**. Alternatively, you would have to disassociate your lambda from a VPC.